# Is there a better way to listen to events on Mongoose models?

Tags: mongoose, events, listener

When the connection is created this function is ran:

```
function setupModelListenersForConnection(c){
    var Job = c.model('Job');
    Job.addListener('created', function(jobInstance){
    });
    console.log('Models have been wired!');
}
```

In the schema for the job I have this:

```
JobSchema.post('save', function(next){
  this.db.models.Job.emit('created', this);
})
```

What I don't really like is `this.db.models.Job` and I think there is a better way to do it ;) thanks a lot

Why I need it?

Imagine a job is created. I want to update the worker and set it's current job and a new state (busy).

I like to decouple the models, in this way the Job model doesn't have to know about the Worker model. Only knows some details about a worker as id and name.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you ever get an answer to this question?

Comment: not much :/ but contact me if you find any answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how [mongoose-lifecycle](http://github.com/fzaninotto/mongoose-lifecycle) does it

```
JobSchema.post('save', function(next){
  var model = this.model(this.constructor.modelName);
  model.emit('created', this);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function connection(mongoose, config, options) {
function connectToMongo() {
  mongoose
    .connect(config.mongo.uri, options)
    .then(
      () => {},
      (err) => {
        console.info('Mongodb error', err);
      }
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('ERROR:', err);
    });
}

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.info('Connected to MongoDB!');
});

mongoose.connection.on('reconnected', () => {
  console.info('MongoDB reconnected!');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(`Error in MongoDb connection: ${error}`);
  mongoose.disconnect();
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
  console.error(
    `MongoDB disconnected! Reconnecting in ${
      options.reconnectInterval / 1000
    }s...`
  );
  setTimeout(() => connectToMongo(), options.reconnectInterval);
});

return {
  connectToMongo
};
```

}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**